# Decay property of the Fourier transform

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R} \to (0,\infty)$ be nonnegative functions on $\mathbb{R}$. If $$
\lim_{|x|\to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 0.
$$
Can we conclude anything about the decay property of their respective Fourier transforms $\hat f,\hat g$? They are defined by
$$
\hat f(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-ixy} f(x)dx,
$$
similar for $\hat g$.
In particular, could we conclude anything such as
$$
\lim_{|y| \to \infty} \frac{|\hat g(y)|}{|\hat f(y)|} = 0,
$$
provided that the division is well-defined?

A related question is [Decay of Fourier Transform of a Schwartz Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240671/decay-of-fourier-transform-of-a-schwartz-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Take $g(x)=e^{-|x|}, f(x)=e^{-|x|/2}$. Fourier transforms of these function can be written down explitly. [Refer to Cauchy distribution in Wikipedia]. The ratio of the FT's actually tends to a  positive constant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason that I am asking is that I would like to compare the decaying property of the Fourier transform of $\exp(-|t|^p)$ for $p>2$ with the one of $\exp(-|t|^2)$. Is there any result in that case? In other words, what happens if the decay rates of the original functions are different?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up comment to the answer above, I have some new findings regarding the question. As a general principle in Fourier transform, also known as Heisenberg's Inequality, see, e.g., Theorem 1.1 in The Uncertainty Principle: A Mathematical Survey by Folland, we would expect that if the original function $f$ decays faster, then its Fourier transform $\hat f$ decays slower. In fact, the theorem says if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\|f\|_{L^2} =1$, then
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 |f(x)|^2 dx \right)\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 |\hat f(x)|^2 dx\right)\geq \frac{1}{16\pi^2},
$$
here $\hat f$ denotes the standard $2\pi$-Fourier transform of $f$. In our setting, i.e., the function $g$ takes the form $t\mapsto \exp(-|t|^p)$ and $f$ is the Gaussian function, if $p=\infty$, then $g$ is compactly supported and $\hat g$ is the Sinc function, which decays much slower than the Gaussian function.

Comment: What do you mean by "In our set?"  What is $p$?    Did you mean "sinc function" instead of "since function?"

Comment: It should be "setting", I have corrected the answer. Thanks for the comment.